# Google VM zone does not have enough resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My VM crashed and giving me the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzCvj.png):

> Starting VM instance "xxxx" failed. Error: The zone 'projects/xxxxxx/zones/us-east1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Also I am not able to create any new Instance on same Zone due to same error, but can create on any other zone. Can anyone help me in how to bring the instance back again or how to get the existing data from that vm.

Comment: Looks like you're stuck with "try again later".

Answer (score 2):

I am really sorry that you are experiencing this issue, but here is a way to get your instance's data back.

1. Create a snapshot of your disk as indicated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_zonal_snapshot) and select the source disk (your GCE disk) and choose Multi-regional as the location so you can create the new GCE instance in other region.
2. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) the new GCE instance based on the snapshot, here you can change the region/zone in which your instance will be created.
3. You should be able to access your data as in the original instance.